# Context Menu not appearing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make an extension that has a context menu, however I can't seem to get it to work, even when using boiler plates or other guides I've followed, it never seems to work. The Google boilerplate examples work at creating the menus but I can't seem to work from there because none of the code I put in executes.

I just got the image from the web so the actual dimensions are 300x300 (not sure if that matters but the documents said an icon was 'preferred' (and it seems to work as "default_icon")

This is what I have so far:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Point",
  "version": "0.1",

  "browser_action":{
   "default_icon":"toThePoint_Logo.png",
   "default_popup":"popup.html"
    },

  "permissions": [
      "contextMenus"],

   "background": {
       "scripts": ["main.js"],
       "persistent": false
    }
   ,"icons" : {
       "16": "toThePoint_Logo.png"
   }
}
```

**main.js**

```js
chrome.contextMenus.removeAll();

chrome.contextMenus.create({
      "id": "contextID",
      "title": "first",
      "contexts": ["all"],
      "onclick": function() {
        alert('first');
      }
});
```

Comment: Start by checking the background page console. There should be an error I think. The documentation says onclick property isn't supported in event page, instead use [chrome.contextMenus.onClicked listener](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#event-onClicked)

Comment: @wOxxOm , wow... I had read that post and tried it but it didn't work.
Although I was very tired at the time. 
This is indeed a duplicate of that other post. do I delete it? Will an admin mark it? can I still give you some kind of +1?